# ORMInvalidArgumentException: A new entity was found through the relationship For multiple iterations

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am getting doctrine error as explained below. I checked the solutions given in other questions but it's not something I am looking for.

So basically i have an action for generating exam cards as(just putting relevant code)-

```
function generateExamCardAction{
    $examSetting = $this->getExamSetting();
    $this->insertExamCard($classId, $examSetting);
    $insertedExamCard = $this->fetchExamCard($classId);
    $this->generatePdf($insertedExamCard);
}
```

And the insertExamCard function goes like this:

```
function insertExamCard($classId, $examSetting){
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $examCard = new ExamCard();
    $examCard->setClassId($classId);
    $examCard->setExamSetting($examSetting);
    $em->persist($examCard);
    $em->flush();
    $em->clear();
}
```

And the doctrine association between ExamCard and ExamSetting is as:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ExamSetting")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ExamSettingId", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $examSetting;
```

Please note that i have not cascaded it using `cascade={"persist"}` beacuse i dont want to manipulate *ExamSetting* table at any cost as it's master table.

Till here everything is working fine. ExamCard is getting inserted properly, then fetched properly and then generating pdf properly.

But now I have to iterate the logic in generateExamCardAction() for multiple classes.
So it would be like this:

```
function generateExamCardAction{
    $examSetting = $this->getExamSetting();
    foreach($classes as $classId){
        $this->insertExamCard($classId, $examSetting);
        $insertedExamCard = $this->fetchExamCard($classId);
        $this->generatePdf($insertedExamCard);
    }
}
```

In this case the the first iteration is working fine.  That is for 1st class it's inserting ExamCard, then fetching and generating pdf properly.

But for second iteration it's giving below error:

> Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException: A new entity was found
>   through the relationship
>   'Application\Entity\ExamCard#examSetting' that was not
>   configured to cascade persist operations for entity

I believe the problem is with `$em->clear()`.

I tried by changing it to `$em->clear($examCard)`. In that case it doesn't give error but the data fetched by fetchExamCard() doesn't have ExamSetting fields set in ExamCard.

Could you please help me find why it's working for single iteration but not for multiple iterations?

Comment: Why do you call `clear()` at all?

Comment: @Flying If i remove `clear()` then `fetchExamCard()` is not able fetch the persisted record somehow with the details of ExamSetting.

Comment: I don't know what `fetchExamCard()` do, but `clear()` removes all your entities from identity map and hence they're not available for Doctrine and need to be re-fetched. It should have negative impact on performance. Back to the topic: are you sure that object that is assigned to `enamSetting` is properly persisted to Doctrine?